# Unity inject complex constructor object in app.config

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, app-config

I have a class MyProvider that accepts a settings object as the constructor parameter. Does anyone know if Unity supports passing complex objects as parameters via app.config configuration?

Here's what I've tried so far (didn't work)

```
<register type="IProvider" mapTo="MyProvider">
    <constructor>
        <param name="settings">
            <value>
         <MyProviderSettings>
             <UserId>YYYYYYYY</UserId>
             <Password>XXXXXX</Password>
             <OtherPropery>ZZZZZZZ</OtherPropery>
         </MyProviderSettings>
        </value>
        </param>
```

I get an error "Invalid element MyProviderSettings"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to the docs, you define a custom type converter for this. The type converter will convert a string value for any value of any type.

```
<constructor>
<param name="param1">
    <value value="42" />
</param>
<param name="param2">
    <value value="aieou" typeConverter="VowelTypeConverter" />
</param>
</constructor>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914(v=pandp.20).aspx#config_value

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response, Wiktor. It appears if I want to keep using some form of XML to define the passed object, I need to write a converter that uses XmlSerializer. Then I would use something like this:

<value value="&lt;MyProviderSettings&gt;....."

Not particularly convenient but should work.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: I am afraid there is no other solution or at least nothing else comes to my mind.